# « L'une des X pour laquelle » ou « l'une des X pour lesquelles » ?

Tags: grammaire, usage, choix-de-mot, pluriel

J'hésite dans la formulation d'une phrase. Parmi les deux phrases suivantes, laquelle est correcte et pourquoi ?

> C'est l'une des maisons pour laquelle je serai prêt à …
>
> C'est l'une des maisons pour lesquelles je serai prêt à …

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> C'est une des maisons qui m'**ont** fait rêver.
> C'est une des maisons que j'ai pris**es** en photo.

Avec un sujet ou un complément d'objet direct, le pluriel s'impose. Donc je ne vois pas pourquoi il en serait autrement avec un complément d'objet indirect.

Cela se comprend sémantiquement : toutes les maisons en question m'on fait rêver, j'ai pris toutes les maisons en photo.

Cela dit, le singulier est peut-être possible lorsque la subordonnée se rapporte à un élément à la fois. Dans ton exemple, cela peut donc dépendre de ce qu'exprime cette subordonnée.

> C'est une des maisons pour lesquelles j'aime faire ces promenades photographiques. [Je photographie en général plusieurs maisons par promenade.]
> C'est une des maisons pour lesquelles/laquelle je vendrais la mienne sans hésiter. [Si je vends ma maison, c'est pour en acheter une autre et une seule.]

J'ai quand même l'impression que le singulier ici tient plus de la figure de style (qui peut se permettre de malmener la grammaire).

Quelques exemples littéraires (« une des personnes pour [lesquelles](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22une%20des%20personnes%20pour%20lesquelles%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_fr)/[laquelle](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22une%20des%20personnes%20pour%20laquelle%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_fr) », je liste toutes les occurrences sur Google Books) :

> Cependant Le Sueur, par le crédit de l'une des personnes pour lesquelles il avait exécuté des peintures, avait obtenu (…) ([Édouard Mennechet](http://books.google.com/books?id=d8_TOJTka_0C&pg=PA46&dq=%22une+des+personnes+pour+lesquelles%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Ir1AUr_5IYak4gS-mIDABg&ved=0CDIQ6AEwAA), 1837)
>
> Si, fortuitement, on annonçait une des personnes pour lesquelles elle y était toujours, (…) ([Felice Blangini](http://books.google.com/books?id=S2M6AAAAcAAJ&pg=PA320&dq=%22une+des+personnes+pour+lesquelles%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Ir1AUr_5IYak4gS-mIDABg&ved=0CDoQ6AEwAQ))
>
> l'une des personnes pour lesquelles ce Règlement était fait. ([Ferdinand Cavallera](http://books.google.com/books?id=9gw2uodz_3MC&q=%22une+des+personnes+pour+lesquelles%22&dq=%22une+des+personnes+pour+lesquelles%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Ir1AUr_5IYak4gS-mIDABg&redir_esc=y), 1965)
>
> La femme d'un de ses intimes amis, une des personnes pour laquelle il avait la plus grande affection, (…) ([Louis Marie Quicherat](http://books.google.com/books?id=XvAPAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA310&dq=%22une+des+personnes+pour+laquelle%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=c75AUtrFB9PQ4QTOkoCwDg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22une%20des%20personnes%20pour%20laquelle%22&f=false), 1867)

Cette dernière phrase me semble être un hybride entre « une des personnes pour lesquelles il avait une très grande affection » (superlatif absolu) et « la personne pour laquelle il avait la plus grande affection » (superlatif relatif).

Attention, je suppose ici que le sens est « plusieurs maisons m'ont fait rêver, dont celle-ci ». On pourrait aussi vouloir dire « ce qui m'a fait rêver, c'est une des maisons », auquel cas le pronom relatif devrait être au singulier.

> C'est une des maisons qui m'**a** fait rêver.
> C'est une des maisons que j'ai pris**e** en photo.

Comment: À quoi faites-vous allusion avec **ici** dans « J'ai quand même l'impression que le singulier **ici** tient plus de la figure de style (qui peut se permettre de malmener la grammaire). » ? Du reste, est-ce pourquoi le participe passé de chacune des 4 phrases citées se produisent au singulier ? Ou ai-je manqué qqch ? SVP, prière de répondre dans votre réponse qui rend plus facile la lecture.

Answer (score 2):

> C'est l'une des maisons pour laquelle je serai prêt à ...

le "laquelle" invoque une raison particulière à cette maison.

> C'est l'une des maisons pour lesquelles je serai prêt à ...

le "lesquelles" invoque l'ensemble de maisons dont on parle, donc invoque "des maisons".

Answer (score 1):

Je dirai tout simplement que, dans cette construction comme dans les similaires, le genre et le nombre du pronom sont ceux du nom auquel il fait référence.

- Dans « *C’est l’une des maisons pour lesquelles je serai prêt à …* », *lesquelles* fait référence à « les maisons ».
- Dans ~« *C’est l’une des maisons pour laquelle je serai prêt à …* » (que je trouve douteux), *laquelle* fait référence à « l’une des maisons ».

Maintenant, pourquoi trouvé-je cet exemple douteux ? Tout simplement parce que, si tu parles « des maisons pour lesquelles », l’article défini est justifié par le fait que tu précises les maisons dont tu parles : ce sont celles « pour lesquelles … ». Mais, du coup, tu ne peux pas parler « des maisons pour laquelle … ». En effet, le « pour laquelle » ne permet pas d’identifier « les maisons » puisqu’il ne s’y réfère pas ; par conséquent, l’article défini me semble incorrect. Cela dit, un habile auteur pourrait me fournir un contre exemple acceptable.

Remarquons que si l’on se débarrasse de l’article défini, plus aucun problème ne se pose. Les deux exemples suivant sont limpides :

> C’est l’une de ces maisons pour laquelle…
>
> C’est l’une de ces maisons pour lesquelles…

Comment: L'exemple de Gilles "La femme d'un de ses intimes amis, une des personnes pour laquelle il avait la plus grande affection, (…) (Louis Marie Quicherat, 1867)" ne vous convient-il pas ? Il est vrai que ce n'est pas habituel, mais *laquelle* n'est pas obligé d'être accolée à sa référence.

Comment: J’avoue ne pas avoir relu sa réponse avant de proposer la mienne. Cela dit, cet exemple me semble toujours étrange. Je l’éviterai au quotidien.