# « Objets » et « compléments d'objet », est-ce la même chose ?

Tags: grammaire, terminologie

Je suis en quête d'une réponse pratique et appliquée, utile à ceux qui apprennent la langue française, et pas d'une réponse théorique ni autour de la linguistique. Si on désire discourir de cela, prière de formuler deux réponses à part, histoire de ne pas les mêler.

Y a-t-il les différences et similarités entre « objet [in]direct » et « complément d’objet [in]direct » ?

Il me paraît qu'en anglais, on s'entretient la plupart du temps de *[in]direct object*, et pas de *[in]direct object complement*. En français, c'est l'inverse ; **complément** figure toujours avec **d’objet [in]direct** ?

J'indique en référence ces fils de discussion en français :

- https://french.stackexchange.com/a/7606/1995

et ceux-ci en anglais :

- [U Ottawa](http://www.writingcentre.uottawa.ca/hypergrammar/objcompl.html)
- [Capital Community College Foundation](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/objects.htm)
- [Towson University](http://www.towson.edu/ows/nouns.htm), [Object vs Complement](http://www.usingenglish.com/forum/linguistics/70148-difference-between-complement-object.html)
- [Grammar Monster](http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/object_complement.htm).

Answer (score 2):

L'évolution du vocabulaire employé pour l'enseignement de la grammaire (sans compter la variation à l'intérieur d'une seule langue) et la différence dans l'emploi des termes viennent compliquer un peu la réponse. Je parlerai de grammaire "didactique" pour discuter du langage qu'on rencontre généralement dans les manuels et les cours de français (les termes employés en linguistiques pouvant varier considérablement selon la théorie sur laquelle on se base).

Dans les pages *anglaises* que tu nous donne, le terme *object* désigne ce qu'on appelle en grammaire didactique le *complément* (peu importe son type), et *complement* est employé pour désigner ce qu'on appelle un *attribut*. Le *verb complement* mentionné dans une des pages me semble une catégorie injustifiée et injustifiable puisque ce "complement" n'a clairement pas le même rôle grammatical que les attributs.

J'ajouterai au passage que l'enseignement de la grammaire au Québec ne reconnaît pas, à ma connaissance, les complément d'objet second ou d'attribution, qui sont traités comme de simples compléments d'objet indirect (quoique la nouvelle terminologie emploie simplement *complément indirect*).

---

Le mot *objet* dans *complément d'objet* n'a **aucune existence indépendante de *complément*** : il n'est pas, à ma connaissance, employé comme terme dans la grammaire didactique en dehors de cette expression, et même mon *Petit Robert* ne définit que l'expression, et non le mot. Bref, "complément d'objet" tient plus du nom composé (et presque indécomposable, en l’occurrence). Je n'ai pas la moindre idée de pourquoi ce mot a été ajouté dans cette construction à l'origine.

Grevisse (Le bon usage, 14e ed., §279) note que *objet direct* est un usage valide et parfois employé. Au Québec, on fait l'inverse et désormais, on parle (comme j'y ai fait brièvement allusion plus haut) de *complément direct* ou *complément indirect*, ce qui n'était pas le cas à l'époque de mes études il y a 10-15 ans.

Comment: Il semble que le vocabulaire à convergé. Est-ce que ça vaudrait de coup de discuter sur méta d'une possible recommandation (voire uniformisation) concernant la terminologie à employer sur ce site ?

Comment: @Circeus: Pourriez-vous faire remarquer où vous avez `fait brièvement allusion plus haut de complément direct ou complément indirect` ? Au demeurant, quelles sont les différences entre *object (in English)* vs **objet [indirect]** vs **complément [in]direct** vs **complément objet [indirect]**?  Prière de répondre dans votre réponse SVP.

Comment: Désolé, mais je ne vais pas répéter que je fais allusion à la terminologie dans la parenthèse qui conclut ma réponse originale, et j'ai déjà répondu (à mon sens) très clairement à la seconde question: (en) *object* = (fr) complément.

Answer (score 0):

Au risque d'être théorique, **il faut circonscrire le terrain en éliminant ce qui n'est pas complément d'objet**, à savoir :

- *les compléments de nom ou de pronom* ("vous attendez une réponse à votre question") ;
- *les compléments qui sont un infinitif ou une proposition* ("vous espérez que l'on vous répondra") ;
- *les compléments d'agent*, à la voix passive, qui seraient sujets à la voix active, mais que l'on peut éventuellement supprimer ("la souris a été attrapée par le chat") ;
- *les compléments circonstanciels*, qui ne font que préciser des détails, que l'on pourrait supprimer et dont la place est libre ("vous avez posé une question ce matin" ou "ce matin, ... ").

**Restent trois compléments d'objet** (par "objet", j'entends aussi "personne") :

- **le complément d'objet direct**, d'un verbe transitif direct, COD, (sans préposition, désignant ce qui est visé : "vous avez posé une question") ; [réponse à : "qui ?" ou "quoi ?"]
- **le complément d'objet second** (ou : d'attribution), COS, qui, comme son nom l'indique, n'existe que s'il a déjà un COD : "j'espère éclairer le lecteur par ma réponse". Il est toujours précédé d'une préposition, sauf si celle-ci est fondue dans un pronom décliné : "je consulte Stack Exchange et j'en remercie les collaborateurs" ;
- **le complément d'objet indirect**, d'un verbe transitif indirect avec préposition : "je ne sais pas ce dont je parle" ; [réponse à : "à qui /quoi ?", "de qui / quoi ?].

---

**L'anglais ne pose pas plus de difficultés**, sauf pour un francophone qui doit retenir essentiellement deux choses :

- un verbe doit toujours être appris avec la ou les préposition(s) qui l'accompagne(nt) : un même sens peut être exprimée de façon transitive dans une langue, mais intransitivement dans l'autre ;
- en règle générale, et s'il n'est pas trop long, le complément suit immédiatement le verbe, s'il est transitif.

"He carefully studied his lesson" ou "He studied his lesson carefully" (plus insistant sur le soin). Mais *pas* : "He studied carefully his lesson"

Cependant : "His fellows laughed heartily because he had not understood".

Remarques :

- les anglophones nomment "prepositions" certaines "post-positions" ;
- les constructions divergent souvent : "He was laughed at".

---

**Les dénominations sont néanmoins superficiellement différentes** : en anglais, on se contente de dire "*object*" pour "complément d'objet", et "*adverbial phrase of ...* " pour "complément circonstanciel de ... ".

C'est que, parmi de nombreux sens, "de" entre deux substantifs désigne une relation d'appartenance à une classe, une catégorie (maison de retraite, employé de magasin) ; il faut comprendre "complément d'objet" comme :

a) c'est un complément ;

b) parmi toutes les sortes de compléments qui existent, celui-ci est de la catégorie des objets.

Si l'on ne précise pas la nature d'une circonstance, on peut dire de même "complément de circonstance", c'est-à-dire qui appartient à l'ensemble des détails non indispensables ; mais il serait trop lourd de dire "complément de circonstance de lieu, de temps, etc.").

**La terminologie en français est donc plus explicite, sans intérêt majeur, car l'anglais laissant deviner qu'il s'agit d'un complément est finalement tout aussi clair.**

Comment: Ça n'a aucun sens d'éliminer "les compléments qui sont un infinitif ou une proposition". Ces complément ne forme pas une classe séparée! *Un infinitif ou une proposition peuvent constituer n'importe quel des types de complément que tu listes.* (Dans l'exemple que tu cites, c'est clairement un COD.)

Comment: @Circeus: Je vous suis reconnaissant. Toutefois, je reste embarassé. Je ne pige pas encore pourquoi on s'entretient de **le complement d'objet direct/indirect/second** et non pas de **l'objet direct/indirect/second**. Prière de répondre dans votre réponse et non pas en tant qu'un commentaire.

Comment: @MarkThorin: Je vous suis reconnaissant et ai plussoyé. Pourriez-vous expliciter votre dernière phrase en gras ? À quoi est la terminologie en français `sans intérêt majeur` ? Si l'anglais `laisse deviner` que *object* = **complément d'objet**, alors comment est-ce `finalement tout aussi clair`? Prière de répondre dans votre réponse SVP.